# How to share a question/answer/comment to facebook?

Tags: support, facebook

I want my friend in facebook see my questions/answers/comments which I posted in stackoverflow/stackexchange-sites. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [Facebook bookmarklet](http://www.facebook.com/share_options.php). For answers, just click the link button first.

Comment: This is right what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There's no automatic way, but we do have Facebook and Twitter sharing buttons on public beta Stack Exchange 2.0 sites:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

[image]

There might be something on stackapps as well? Yep, 3 pretty cool looking apps!

https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/facebook

Comment: woooo jeffs back! wait that was 2010.